# org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) when using @Lazy Anottaion in AuditTrailListener

Tags: java, spring-boot

**AuditTrailListener**

```
@Component
public class AuditTrailListenerSchedule {

private final NotificationService notificationService;
private final EmployeeService employeeService;

@Autowired
@Lazy
public AuditTrailListenerSchedule(NotificationService notificationService, EmployeeService employeeService) {
    this.notificationService = notificationService;
    this.employeeService = employeeService;
}


@PostPersist
public void afterAnyCreateSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Employee employee = employeeService.findByUsername(auth.getName());


    Notification newNotification = Notification.builder()
            .employee(schedule.getEmployee())
            .date(dateCreated())
            .message(String.format("%s added new schedule form %s to %s ", employee.getFullName(), schedule.getFrom(), schedule.getTo()))
            .build();

    notificationService.save(newNotification);
}
```

When I use `employeeService.findByUsername(auth.getName())` I end up with this exception:

> rg.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.mikedev.HRMSystem.model.Schedule entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

If I use `employeeService.findById(1L)` I got no problems it's find the user without exception, everything is same in repository for the find by username is Optional and throw exception when is not entity with that username found. I think this may be from the `@Lazy` annotation. How can I get around this problem and find the employee with the given logged user username.